# Can't login to my main administrator account?

Tags: password, administrator, accounts

After recovering from the warning failed to connect to lvmetad error I released when I tried to login to the first account I ever created was not logging in I typed in the right password it says the password was right then give me a wallpaper and logout automatically and bring me back to the password box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of things you can do :

Delete `.Xauthority` and try to login

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
```

If that fails delete `.ICEauthority`

```
sudo rm .ICEauthority
```

if that fails 
press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> login and then run this command:

```
startx
```

The last solution would be to purge the video drivers.

Let me know if any of these work.